# Stop events inside delegate with same handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table on which I use delegate on tr, each row also has a button. I need to perform some action on this button click. The click event on the button fires when it is clicked but it fires the number of times a user clicked anywhere else in the row plus the one time the button is clicked.

Here's a code snippet

**JS**

```
$('.detailTable').delegate('tr', 'click', function() {
  console.log('clicked in row');
  $('#saveButton').click(function(event) {
    console.log('clicked on button');
    return false;
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="detailTable">
  <tr>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>
      <button id="saveButton">
        Save
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ujwal_15/rkfvoq4o/1/)

Comment: Why are you bind event inside delegated click handler? Also you should use `.on()`

Comment: FYI, you really should be using `.on()` instead of `.delegate()` unless you're using a really old version of jQuery.

Comment: I cannot use .on() as I am using jquery 1.6.4

Comment: In that case you should really upgrade the version of jQuery you're using. That's almost 5 years out of date.

Comment: @Satpal Do you mean I should call .click('button') outside .delegate

Comment: @UjwalRatra why do you need an event to be delegated?

Comment: @Jai I do add new rows to the table dynamically.

Comment: @UjwalRatra can you define _new rows_ plz? that would help us to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you didn't mention why you are using event delegation? As this isn't required if you are not creating/loading any new elements after page load via some code or using ajax.

The issue is you have a click event bound on the `tr`, which in turn binds an event on the `button`. So each time you click on `tr` it registers a new event so the callback is fired for each registration. ***If you click in the `tr` 3 times then for `button` the callback will be executed 3 times.***

*In my opinion you should just use normal `click` events.*

---

You might do this:

```
$('.detailTable').delegate('tr', 'click', function() {
  console.log('clicked in row');
}).delegate('#saveButton', 'click', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked on button');
    return false; // does two things e.preventDefault() & e.stopPropagation()
    // and this will stop the event to bubble up to the tr element.
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the issue. Are there no solutions to this without using .on() ? I want the just the button click to be executed.

Comment: There is, wait i am updating it.

Comment: @UjwalRatra you can use it now.

Comment: This works as expected, I have one more doubt. Can I extend this for other buttons too. Suppose I have one more button in the row, what do I do then?

Comment: use comma separated string like `'btn1, btn2, btn3'` etc.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct behaviour as you register a new handler for the button click each time you click on the row. Its not totally clear for me what you want to achieve.

To get the row from the button click event, you can try this:

```
$("#saveButton").click(function() {
   var $item = $(this).closest("tr");
});
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: I don't need row from the button.

Comment: Then just use a class on the button and register the click on each button like so:

$(".saveButton").click(function() {
   // do something
});

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can't have multiple buttons with the same id.  That's illegal HTML and will just cause problems for selectors.  I'd suggest using a class name instead.

Then, you never want to be binding a new click handler every time something else is clicked.  That just gets the click handlers piling up and you get multiple callbacks for each click handler you registered.

Then, unless you're using a really old version of jQuery, you should be using `.on()` instead of `.delegate()`.

So, here's what I would suggest:

```
<table class="detailTable">
  <tr>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>
      <button class="saveButton">
        Save
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>
      <button class="saveButton">
        Save
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Code:

```
// save button click handlers
$('.detailTable').on('click', '.saveButton', function(e) {
    // don't let button click handler propagate to the row
    // you can remove this e.stopPropagation() line if you want
    // a click to trigger both button and row click handlers
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('clicked on save Button');
});

// row click handlers
$('.detailTable').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    console.log('clicked in row');
});
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hy69py9m/

---

FYI, if you're not dynamically creating elements in this table, then there's no need for delegated event handling and you could just use static selectors to map your event handlers.

Comment: I am not using multiple buttons with same id, the snippet was just a sample. What I am exactly doing is each time I click a row, I attach id with the corresponding save button in that row. Now whenever I click the save button, I want it to fire once but it fires (number of times row is clicked + one) times.

Comment: @UjwalRatra - Stop binding a new click handler for the button EVERY time the row is clicked.  That's a problem.  If you want more detailed help on how else to solve your problem, you will have to show more detail on the problem.  But, the reason you get multiple button click handlers is because you install multiple click handlers.

Comment: @UjwalRatra - The only reason here to use delegated event handling is if you're adding elements to the table dynamically.  If you're not doing that, then there's no reason to use delegated event handling.  You can just use static event handling with direct selector matches.  Since you don't show us the real problem you're trying to solve with this code, we don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: I do add new rows to the table dynamically.

Comment: @UjwalRatra - OK, you are adding rows dynamically.  This answer gets you one click for the row and one click event for the button and it uses `stopPropagation()` to make it so a click in the button does not trigger the row click (though you can remove the `stopPropagation()` if you want the button click to also fire for the row click handler.  So, does this solve your problem?  If not, please explain why.

Comment: I can't use .on(), I am using jquery 1.6.4

Comment: @UjwalRatra - Eeeeck.  Why such an old version of jQuery?  I'd hate to think what bugs are lurking in that version that have long since been fixed in newer versions.  In any case, you can take my above code, swap in `.delegate()` for `.on()` and swap the first two arguments to match the order that `.delegate()` uses.  The general solution is the same whether you're using the now ancient `.delegate()` or `.on()`.  You just have to match the arguments in the right order.  Does this explain the problem you were having?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what your question is but some remarks:

I've made this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6dmqdpn/3/) with your code and some mild edits.

By delagating an event listener (the one with the button) inside another (the one with the row), there has to be first clicked on the row (or on the button, because it is in the row) only after that the event on the button will be listened to.

If you have multiple rows you have to make sure to not use the same id for every button. In the fiddle I have used a classname which solves that problem.

I suggest using two seperate listeners:

```
$('.detailTable tr').click(function() {
  console.log('clicked in row');
});

$('.detailTable tr .saveButton').click(function(event) {
  console.log('clicked on button');
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

the `event.stopPropagation()` ([jQuery api](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/))  prevents the click to bubble up to the row so, when clicking on the button the row will not be clicked.